# Overflowing content horizontally sans scrollbar with drag and drop

Tags: javascript, css, drag-and-drop, html-lists, overflow

I need to rig up some `<li>` items so that they can be dragged and dropped horizontally. Their container is a variable width though. I need it so that if the `<li>` is dragged to the far right edge, the content within the container (other `<li>`s) will scroll to the left so that the active `<li>` can be dropped on the far right.

Can anyone help?

Fiddle at http://jsfiddle.net/j_holtslander/5WpT6/

Answer (score 0):

your problem is with the overflow being hidden. If you are hiding the overflow, you cannot see the last **li** if the browser's width is lower then the **container**'s width, because they are hidden.

If you what that functionality to work as planned you should, for usability reasons, let the **li** elements flow over the browser's width change, not hiding them.